# how to save a sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv, save, xlsm

I'm building a form that when you fill it up, it should generate 2 files as output.

In order to do that I have 2 sheets in the background that I fill up depending on what the user entered a button to save them (as csv).

This is the code for saving the sheet-

```
Worksheets("worksheetname").SaveAs Filename:="C:\path" & name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

The problem is that after the user presses the button, the form that he is filling is now 'saved as csv', and not xlsm like before.

Is there a way to avoid that from happening? to generate the output without affecting the form?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I underastand your question, you are saving it as `.csv` so it's only saving the worksheets, without the VBA `User_Form`s. If you want to keep the `User_Form`s then you need to save it as `.xlsm`

Comment: Specify the following points: What exactly is the state you start with (all data/sheets etc.)? What is the state you want to arrive at (what files with what data saved where in what format)?

Comment: Create a new workbook for each new worksheet, then save each worksheet as a .csv as you do currently. That should leave the workbook with the form intact.

Comment: @DavidG I'm starting with a xlsm file that has 3 worksheets, I want the user to fill whatever he fill, pres on a button and then I want 2 csv files to be generated, without changing my file. the data in the csv files should come from sheets in my xlsm file.

Comment: @T.G. I see. What of the data from the 3 sheets needs to go into the 2 csv files? So it all works great, except you need to get back to the initial state of the xlsm, correct?

Comment: @DavidG thank you, A.S.H's answer work great for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the original workbook intact, you need to fork a *copy* of the worksheet before saving it as CSV. Try this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("worksheetname").copy '  Forks a copy of the sheet in a new, active WB
With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Path\" & name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```