# Powershell Worksheet.saveAs saving wrong Sheet

Tags: excel, powershell, save-as, comobject

I am trying to save a specific Excel Sheet from a Macro Enabled Excel Workbook (xlsm) via Powershell to csv to upload it into a database. This is done via Powershell since it needs to be automated along with some more data processing etc.

**The Situation:**

1. I have a list of excel files in a directory, each having the same structure/sheets.
2. I parse each file to a Powershell function which creates a new Excel Object and opens the workbook.
3. In the next step I am trying to save a specific sheet (here Sheet with Index 2)

**The Problem:**

1. Iterating through each Worksheet and saving them gives me all Sheets including the one I am looking for (Sheet 2)
2. Accessing Sheets 2 via `$ws = $wb.Worksheets(2)` also gives me the right Sheet (according `$ws.name`) but saving `$ws` via `$ws.SaveAs("$destinationDirectory" + $File.BaseName + ".csv", 6)` results in a csv file containing Sheet 1.

I have saved Worksheets with basically exactly the same code successfully before (except instead of xlsm I was dealing with xlsx).

**Code**

```
Function ExcelToCsv ($File) {
    echo "Converting $($File.Name) to csv..."

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False;

    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets(2)
    
    echo "ws is:" + $ws.name # Correctly printing Worksheet name of Sheet 1

    $ws.SaveAs("$destinationDirectory" + $File.BaseName + ".csv", 6) # Saving Sheet 1 instead of Sheet 2

    $wb.Close($True);
    }
}

foreach ($file in $files){
  ExcelToCsv -File $file; 
}
```

**Workaround**

My current workaround is to iterate through the sheets via foreach

```
$n = 1
foreach($ws in $wb.Worksheets){
    $ws.SaveAs("$destinationDirectory" + $File.BaseName + "-$($n).csv", 6)
    $n = $n+1
}
```

And deleting any unwanted sheets (recognized by $n != 2) via

```
Remove-Item "$($destinationDirectory)*-[13456789].csv";
```

Which works but is not really optimal.
Also: checking for `$n -eq 2` in the foreach and only saving that sheet also does not work since it will simply save sheet 1 again.

And ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is to first copy the worksheet to a new workbook... similar to this VBA approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941546/macro-to-save-only-the-active-worksheet) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568810/how-to-save-a-sheet-in-vba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a frustrating afternoon I eventually worked this one out - you need to call Activate against the sheet you want to save e.g.

```
$sheet = $book.sheets.item('User_Specified_Report')
$Sheet.Activate()
$sheet.SaveAs($newName,6)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot when I come around to using this script again.

I have not thought about using Activate here.